# nested table in html

Tags: html

very simple issue but i am struggling to get it resolved. the issue is i have used table with 100% width and then in one of TD i have used div with 100% width, thing is div is crossing the TD limit and displaying beyond TD space.

Note : this issue is only with chrome, other browser working fine.

```
<table width=100%><tr>
<td>
  <div width=100%> here are contents </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

same thing is happening when i use nested table something like below

```
<table class="outer-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        I'm some content!
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't the div already has 100% of the table's width? Why do you specify it?

Comment: put "display: inline-block;" for div too

Comment: I don't see a problem with this is in Chrome: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaPNz/2/)**. Am I missing something?

Comment: `<div width=100%>` is very unusual -_- Try to follow specs, less problems you'll have.

Comment: Hi All, thank you for reply.. i have checked it using program suggested by @symlynk and can see there is no problem with width.. but dont know yet whether i am missing something in my code.. will check that out..

Answer (score 0):

the div will be taking width of table if give 100% to the `div` or the `td` . how do u want that one.